# Dynamic tableview columns for MacOS application in swift

Tags: swift, macos, sqlite, cocoa, tableview

I have a database (*SQLite*) driven app for macOS, which is working fine in console app. However, I decided to create a GUI for this app.

Currently, I am stuck on the problem with different numbers of columns. Can someone please make a template in ***swift*** or explain how to create **dynamic** number of columns in **tableview**.

I know number of columns which each button/action will return.

> Simply I have query functions, which select some columns and returns. And I want to bind those columns to tableview.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+nstableview+add+column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:**

```
func createTable(columntitle: [String]) {
    //preparing tableView for new columns
    self.tableView.tableColumns.forEach {
        self.tableView.removeTableColumn($0)
    }
    //adding new columns to the tableView
    for title in columntitle{
        let column = NSTableColumn(identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: title))
        column.title = title
        self.tableView.addTableColumn(column)
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```